# React-Router - Run a parent route loader function each time one if its sub-routes is matched

Tags: reactjs, react-router, client-side-routing

Is it possible to re-run a root route loader function each time a sub-route is matched instead of just on the first time the root route is matched?

I'm trying to handle some redirect logic in the loader of my root route, but while it works the first time around on subsequent navigation between the root's sub-routes the root loader doesn't run.

This leaves me to handle the redirect logic inside the root component as a side effect as well.

I'd prefer to handle redirects from the root loader and before rendering the sub-routes, but as far is I understand since I'm never navigating away from the root route the loader is "correctly" only running once.

**Can I set a parent route loader to run each time one of its children routes is matched?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like for the root/ancestor route loader to run more often than just when *that* route loads (*and a few other reasons*) then use the [`shouldRevalidate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/should-revalidate) prop on the parent route to conditionally run the loader more often.

According to the docs there are a few ways a route's data is revalidated.

> There are several instances where data is revalidated, keeping your UI
> in sync with your data automatically:
>
> - After an action is called from a .
> - After an action is called from a <fetcher.Form>
> - After an action is called from useSubmit
> - After an action is called from a fetcher.submit
> - When the URL params change for an already rendered route
> - When the URL Search params change
> - When navigating to the same URL as the current URL
>
> If you define `shouldRevalidate` on a route, it will first check the
> function before calling the route loader for new data. If the function
> returns `false`, then the loader will not be called and the existing
> data for that loader will persist on the page.

The most trivial solution would be to simply return `true` and the route will be revalidated any time any the URL changes.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Parent />,
    loader,
    shouldRevalidate: () => true,
    children: [
      ....
    ],
  }
]);
```

An alternative might also be to check the current URL's path against the next URL's path.

```js
shouldRevalidate: ({ currentUrl, nextUrl }) => {
  return nextUrl.pathname === "/"                // revalidate parent page
    || currentUrl.pathname !== nextUrl.pathname; // on any path change
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-run-a-parent-route-loader-function-each-time-one-if-its-sub-route]

The logic you choose to revalidate the parent route is really up to you and your app's and that route's specific use case.